# How to dispaly post informations (such as titles) in an admin plugin menu page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to develop a WP plugin to show post(or page) related information (such as show all post title in a list) in an admin menu page. I tried to use "The Loop", but it seems like "The Loop" cannot be accessed in Dashboard.

I have achieved my goal by using $wpdb to query database directly.

But is there a better or safer way to load post information in a dashboard menu page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use wp_query within the dashboard.  This will allow you to create a private query that you have total control of and it works exactly like the query you know and love from Wordpress themes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```